# How to remove value from array by value

Tags: php, arrays

here i am trying to remove value from array, here i am passing action and id to page. i am checking if the values has been set and then perform action.

i want to remove value from array by value. here product_id is the value i am passing and the value has to be removed from array.

for ex:`action=remove&product_id=22` the value 22 has to be removed from array

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['product_id'])){
        if($_GET['action'] == "add"){
            $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];            
            $_SESSION['cart'][] =$product_id;
        }

        if($_GET['action'] == "remove"){
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]);
            echo "product_remove";
        }
    }    
?>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Use `array_search()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS @Rizier said in the comment, use `array_search`, like below:

```
if($_GET['action'] == "remove"){
   $key = array_search ( $product_id, $_SESSION['cart'] );
   unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
   echo "product_remove";
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'remove') {
    if (array_key_exists($product_id, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]);
        echo 'product_remove';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use array_search($product_id, $_SESSION['cart']);

This will get you the key to unset.
If you want to unset it the way you do now, you'll have to use the product id as an key when you add to the cart.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `array_search()` as Rizier123 said, but a more performant way would  be using array_flip and deleting by product_id

```
if($_GET['action'] == "remove"){
   unset(array_flip($_SESSION['cart'])[$product_id]);
   echo "product_remove";
 }
```